# Are there any auditing tools for the Java Play! Framework

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework, audit-trail, audit4j

I am looking for something that will record any crud operations to a specific database table as a separate change history table.  So for example, if I have a table called `Person`, the plugin would record updates to that table in a new table called `PersonAudit`.
I came across [audit4j](http://audit4j.org/), which is basically what I am looking for except it does not seem to work with the Play framework (as far as I can tell).

I am using Play 2.4 and postgresql database.
This is an existing application that I would simply like to add auditing capability to.

Answer (score 0):

I crossed this idea in my project too and in the end I implemented it myself. I overrode methods `save`, `update` and `delete` in the Ebean`s Model class so it saves audit message before committing any changes to the object. It is simple approach but it is working.

I am also using Play 2.4 (Java) and Postgres.